# Store base64 encoded string as file

Tags: android, pdf, base64, ksoap

I have a web service that returns a base64 encoded string of a PDF file.

I want to save this file to the SD Card. but when i try do this, adobe reader tells me that the file is corrupt. obviously i am not saving it properly.

```
byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(resultsRequestSOAP.toString(), 0);

File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/braodcasts.pdf");
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
os.write(pdfAsBytes);
os.close();
```

`resultsRequestSOAP.toString()` looks like this:

```
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
```

Thats just a snippet!

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're opening it for appending. Is there already a file with that name to which you're appending?

Comment: i'm not opening it for append, i'm overwriting the file each time

Comment: Have a look at the PDF in a text editor. The first line should be something like "%PDF-1.4" and the last line should be "%%EOF".

Comment: yeah it is, i just wasn't flushing the file after writing. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I just noticed all pdf's start with `JVBERi0xLj`. And I was only using the first part to check if my pdf changed or not...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you can flush the FileOutputStream before you close it.

```
os.write(pdfAsBytes);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Comment: That surprises me. I would've expected that close would automatically flush any unwritten bytes.

Comment: the `flush()` method in `FileOutputStream` does nothing, it is inherited from `OutputStream`. As the doc says `Flushes this stream. Implementations of this method should ensure that any buffered data is written out. This implementation does nothing.`

Comment: I think it flushes out any remaining bytes that might be in the stream, which explains why it fixed my issue.